# sql query to filter data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

**Table name** - scheme_master

```
column name - book_no2,receipt_no
```

**Table name** - book_issue

```
column name - book_no
```

**Table name** - book_return

```
column name - used_receipt
```

I need to select only those receipt_no from scheme master whose book is created on book issue table.. and  receipt_no which is not present in book_return table.

**FOR EX -**

**DATA in scheme_master**

```
Book_no2     receipt_no

1         -     10

1         -     11

2         -     14

2         -     15

3         -     18

3         -     19
```

**DATE IN Book_issue table**

```
Book_no

3

book        used_receipt

3               18
```

**DATA in book_return table**

In above example there are 3 books created in scheme master table  1,2,3 with diff. receipt OK.

BUT in Book issue table we allot only book no 3.

AND in Book return table we used only receipt no  18.

So i need to select all only receipt no 19 of book 3 from scheme master table...

-plz help to get this...

Below is my query it works fine ...

But this takes lot of time to select records...

FOR EX -it takes more than 6 minutes to Fetch from 30 records...

```
  SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no 
  FROM scheme_master SM 
  Inner join book_issue BI ON BI.book_no = SM.Book_no2  
  where 
  SM.receipt_no not in (select used_receipt from book_return)
```

Comment: Would you mind creating an [SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?! EDIT: the fact your query takes long is because of the NOT IN, you should use a LEFT or RIGHT join for this..

Comment: but sir left join will take all receipt from scheme master...i already tried left join

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
SELECT sm.receipt_no FROM scheme_master as sm, book_return as br
INNER JOIN book_issue as bi ON sm.book_no2 = bi.book_no
WHERE sm.receipt_no != br.used_receipt
```

Comment: sir but this display error ...unknown column sm.book_no2 in on clause

Comment: is book_no2 column is present int scheme_master table?

Comment: the prob is in this line.... book_return as br...when i remove this the query works.....but when i use this qry dispplay error,,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need...

```
SELECT        scheme_master.Book_no2, scheme_master.receipt_no 
FROM            book_return RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         Book_issue ON book_return.book = Book_issue.Book_no RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         scheme_master ON Book_issue.Book_no = scheme_master.Book_no2
WHERE        (Book_issue.Book_no IS NOT NULL) AND  scheme_master.receipt_no != book_return.used_receipt
```

For the second option getting all records even if no book related record...

```
SELECT        scheme_master.Book_no2, scheme_master.receipt_no
FROM            scheme_master LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Book_issue ON Book_issue.Book_no = scheme_master.Book_no2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         book_return ON book_return.book = Book_issue.Book_no
WHERE        (Book_issue.Book_no IS NOT NULL AND scheme_master.receipt_no <> book_return.used_receipt) OR
                         (book_return.used_receipt IS NULL)
```

And finally - similar to your example - but doesn't take  more than a jiffy to run:

```
SELECT        DISTINCT sm.Book_no2, sm.receipt_no
FROM            scheme_master sm LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Book_issue bi ON bi.Book_no = sm.Book_no2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         book_return br ON br.book = sm.Book_no2
WHERE         sm.receipt_no NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT used_receipt FROM book_return)
```

Comment: but your query  return empty result....when book_return table has no records....and when i put records on book_return table...your query works but get all receipt of scheme_master table ...but i need to leave those receipt which are present in book_return table..............

Comment: With the data you supplied in your question, this returns the one record you stated you wanted - Book_no2: 3, receipt_no: 19. Do you mean that you need all records from scheme_master where there is no used_receipt match in book_return? So, if there is no matching record in book_return it will retrieve the record from scheme_master? If so, you should have shown that you wanted those records returned in your question. I have amended the answer to allow for this (and changed the join to a LEFT OUTER if you prefer that). Hope this does it...